# componentWillReceiveProps skips loading if page isn't refreshed

Tags: reactjs, meteor

When I render my page I'm accessing props with `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`. On the initial load the props pass into the page, however, if I click on an internal link and then click back into the page the `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` appears to be skipped so the props don't load. From my reading this appears to be correct, I just don't know what the solution is. Any help?

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const profileCandidateCollection = nextProps.profileCandidate;
    const profileCandidateCollectionId = profileCandidateCollection._id;
    const summary = profileCandidateCollection && profileCandidateCollection.summary;
    console.log("summary: ", summary);

    this.setState({
      summary: summary || '',
      profileCandidateCollectionId: profileCandidateCollectionId || null
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**componentWillRecieveProps**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) is an updating lifecycle method not mounting, it will not get called on initial rendering, it will get triggered only when props will update.

When you are clicking the back button that component will render with this cycle:

```
constructor -> componentWillMount -> render
```

in that cycle `componentWillRecieve` will not get called, once component get rendered and any change happen to props values then it will get called.

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

> componentWillReceiveProps() is invoked before a mounted component
>   receives **new props**. If you need to update the state in response to
>   prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props
>   and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in
>   this method.

Set the initial value inside `constructor` using initial props values, like this:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   let data = props.profileCandidate;
   this.state = {
       summary: data ? data.summary || null,
       profileCandidateCollectionId: data ? data.id : ''
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeh, I just tried your suggestion. When I put it in the constructor the `data` object returns empty.

Comment: use at both the place in constructor and `componentWillRecieveProps` method, `constructor` will get called on initial rendering and `componentWillRecieveProps` will get called when props update.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It doesn't seem very elegant though. Is this 'best practice'?

Comment: its a proper way of doing. Set the initial value in `state` variable then update those values in `componentWillRecieveProps` method, but if that data is fixed means you just want to used those `props` (no update from child) values then don't store in `state` of child component directly use `this.props.KeyName`.